# Drawing graphs in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have completely no experience with C# and WPF but I need to write an application for route finding and then, after having the list of coordinates, I should draw ( and then also have possibility to save it as image file ) a map(grid) with directed graph presenting the found route. 
In case of Windows Forms I would somehow had some idea how to do it, but I do not understand the idea of WPF at all. 
Could someone explain a bit the approach for drawing graphs in WFP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to easily draw graphs in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16479768/how-to-easily-draw-graphs-in-wpf)

Comment: But I do not need such sophisticated tool. Simple drawing a circle at given (X,Y) coordinates, coloring it and then connecting it with another one with straight line is enough for me. I just hoped there will be an easier way. Thanks anyway for link

Comment: Right approach is to get yourself familiar with technology first. There are plenty of books and online-tutorials out there. For example, http://wpftutorial.net/WPFBools.html

Comment: Ofc it is the best approach however not all teachers give you time for learning because they want to see results in a few days ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use Graph# with the GraphLayout control?
http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/

Here you have a tutorial to use Graph# in WPF: http://sachabarbs.wordpress.com/2010/08/31/pretty-cool-graphs-in-wpf/

Comment: Like suggested in the [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17166231/129269), you could also try [GraphX](http://graphx.codeplex.com/)